# ¿Como ordenar los datos en un Listbox? C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, datagrid, listbox

Tengo ciertas dudas en como ordenar mis datos que paso de un datagridview a un listbox, el problema aquí, es que quiero ordenar 2 columnas en un listbox tal y como se muestra en la imagen.
Tengo entendido que puedo solucionar esto introduciendo estos datos en una misma columna del data bajo esa estructura(n1,n2), pero el detalle aqui es que este datagridview se alimenta de tablas de un base de datos, por lo que se genera una columna para cada atributo de la tabla de la DB.

¿Como podria solucionar esto al pasar mis columnas a este listbox bajo ese orden?

ejemplo: las columnas representan las del datagridview

```
col1 col2
```

- 1         1
  2         2
  .         .
  .         .
  .

y como se deberia ir pasando al listbox

```
 c1,c2
```

- 1,1
- 2,2
  .,.
  .,.

[image: listbox]

De ante mano muchas gracias por su ayuda y tiempo.

Comment: Hola! te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Es importante que añadas a tu pregunta que código que estas usando para cargar los datos en el Listbox

Answer (score 0):

Antes de inyectar los valores a la lista, supongo que cada columna la tendrás almacenada en una colección tipo List o Array[] y habrás configurado la propiedad multicolumna en `true' . Esa colección debe poder ordenarla con LinQ.

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(lista1.OrderBy(s => s), lista2.OrderBy(s => s));
```

Espero que sirva de algo pues no soy muy experto en C#.